# Using boolean operators in an if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, calculator

I'm a beginner in coding, and I'm trying to create a quadratic equation calculator using python.

```
while True:
    print("""
        Welcome to DJIGURDA Supreme Quadratic Calculator
        Please enter three values in the form of /'ax^2 + bx +c/'. """)
    a = input("a (first constant)")
    b = input("b (second constant)")
    c = input("c (third constant)")

    if not a.isalpha and not b.isalpha and not c.isalpha:
        d = (float(b)**2) - (4 * float(a) * float(c))
        print(d)
        if d >= 0:
            x_1 = (float(-b) + (d**0.5)) / (2*float(a))
            x_2 = (float(-b) - (d**0.5)) / (2*float(a))
            print("The first variable is equal to %s./n The second variable is equal to %s")[str(x_1), str(x_2)]
        else: 
            print("No real roots.")
    else:
        print("Please enter numerical values.")
```

This code keeps returning "Please enter numerical values." Why is the code not making it past the first "if" statement?

Comment: Brackets. You need each boolean `if` section to have brackets `()` around it.

Comment: try `if (not a.isalpha()) and (not b.isalpha()) and (not c.isalpha()):`

Comment: You need to _call_ `a.isalpha()`.

Comment: ps: you do not need brackets around the if tests (`not` binds stronger than `and`)

Answer (score 8):

You're not calling those methods:

```
c.isalpha()
#        ^^
```

Note that a method or function in Python has a truthy value:

```
>>> bool(''.isalpha)
True
```

So `not a.isalpha` (and others) will always evaluate to `False` and the condition will never pass

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do, since I need numerical input.

Answer (score 0):

You must put brackets around the a.isalpha - like this a.isalpha () this calls the method whereas before it didn't. You must do it for b and c as well

UPDATE

Sorry I just realised someone has answered this like I have way before me, please don't accept my answer and accept theirs!